Input Schema Validation in Graphql JAva
In Java,
I have the Backend Service exposed in GraphQl .
I want to do the input Schema Validation , before it hits the backend service .
let's say my Schema is :
Schema.graphqls
type User{
    id: ID!
    email: String
    password: String
    DOB: String
    account: Account
}

type Account{
    acctid: Int
    acctName: String

}

So ,
Correct Query --> so give data
{
   getAllData{
      email
      account{
          acctName
       }
}

But , if anyone tries below:
Input Validation --> throw error
(since address,ssn) is not there
{
       getAllData{
          email
          address
          ssn
          account{
              acctName
           }
    }

